# images displayed in browser but not on mobile

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using IONIC for my mobile app. My all images displayed in browser but not on mobile. Code,`<img src="/img/exploratory.jpg"  style="height:40px;">`
Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Comment: When you use Remote Debugging, do you see an error? It shouldn't help, but does switching from /img/etc to img/etc help? Are you using the whitelist plugin?

Comment: Are you sure it's not: <img src="img/exploratory.jpg"  style="height:40px;">?

Comment: It works with 'img/exploratory.jpg'. Thanku..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use it as

```
<img src="img/exploratory.jpg"  style="height:40px;">
```

Because if you use `/img`, it becomes in brwoser `localhost:port/img`, but in mobile it becomes `file:///img/` which ofcourse is not right path.And when you use only `img/exploratory.jpg` then in mobile it becomes `file:///android_asset/www/img/explatory.jog` and this is the path where all `www` data is packaged when build is made.

Comment: Thanks for this descriptive answer.